# 2013 Hyundai Accent Can't Clear 420 Code

Tags: engine, p0420, code

2013 Hyundai Accent 255K miles.  Runs great, still gets around 35 MPG.  40K miles ago I was having trouble with 420 code.  Did usual tune up stuff and both O2 sensors.  Ended up replacing the Cat with an aftermarket from Eastern Catalytic.  I noted that the old one had no carbon or scale, I've seen very nasty Cats before.
When I changed the plugs about 15K ago they were normal, no heavy fouling.  Now I'm getting the code again after only 40K miles.  I think it's a false code caused by something else.  What's odd is if I clear the code with a scan tool, turn off the key, turn it back on, and check the scan tool, it still has 2 420 codes, 420 generic pending.  I think this is weird since I haven't run the car after clearing it.  I did some work recently and had the battery disconnected for 4 hours and the code remained.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When was the last time the post cat lambda oxygen sensor was replaced?

Comment: The post Cat O2 sensor was replaced about 50K ago trying to stop the original 420 code.  It's on my to-do list to replace to see if it helps but I have my doubts.  It didn't help last time.  Wondering why the "pending" code won't clear from the computer though.